# Google login with wordpress user registration good practice

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, oauth, google-signin

My project, using ReactJS and Wordpress headless, I use JWT as authentication, now I am developing a way for the user to login with Google.

I check if there is an account with google email, and if not, I register the user by passing the meta provider with the value of google.

What I am not understanding are the following scenarios:

Wordpress needs a username and password, but Goole does not provide me with a password, the idea I had was to use a standard password, but what about when the user already exists or when the user wants to change the password?

I'll leave a part of my code so that you can give me an idea.

Function to sigin with google, using component 'react-google-login', the function is triggered with the component below, after the login is done the validation of the Token.

```
  const signInWithGoogle = async (googleData) => {
    const res = await axios.post('api/auth/google', {
      token: googleData.tokenId,
    });
    console.log('Google Profile');
    console.log(res);

    const googleUser = {
      username: res.data.create.email,
      email: res.data.create.email,
      password: '123456',
      provider: 'google',
      picture: res.data.create.picture,
    };

    await api
      .post('wp/v2/users/register', googleUser)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        onSubmit(googleUser);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
```

component GoogleLogin

```
 <GoogleLogin
            clientId={process.env.GOOGLE_ID}
            buttonText="Login"
            onSuccess={signInWithGoogle}
            onFailure={signInWithGoogle}
            cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
            render={(renderProps) => (
              <button
                type="button"
                className="sign-in"
                onClick={renderProps.onClick}
                disabled={renderProps.disabled}
              >
                <img
                  className="icon google"
                  src={GoogleIcon}
                  alt="google"
                />
                Faça login com o Google
              </button>
            )}
          />
```